# python scraper cannot yield items

Tags: python, scraper, scrapy

my spider.py is like this:

```
class CSpider(scraper.Spider):
    name = 'craig'
    start_urls = ['http://geo.craigslist.org/iso/us/ca']

    def parse(self, response):
        # get url_list
        for url in url_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.method1)

    def method1(self, response):
        # get another url_list
        for url in url_list:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, self.method2)

    def method2(self, response):
        # populate item
        yield item
```

In this, my spider `method2` populates the item. 
and the response for `method2` is dependent on `method1`, and the response of `method1` is dependent on `parse`.

My spider goes through `parse` and `method1` but doesn't enters `method2` which is the main method to yield an item. Can you please tell me where I have made a mistake?

Comment: Where/what is `url_list`? `respone` should be `response`? What is `method3`?

Comment: url_list is the list of urls scraped from the start_url.. Sorry that method3 is method2. I have edited the code

Comment: The main problem here is method2 is never executed here in this case. Can you tell me why

Comment: Please show the complete code. Most likely `url_list` is empty in `method1`. But there could be other reasons too.

Comment: I checked several times.. url_list in method1 is not empty. I also tried by writing a url explicitly.

Comment: @wrufesh still, provide the complete code so that we can try reproducing the problem.

Comment: plese see my full code here https://github.com/Wrufesh/craigscrap/blob/develop/craigscrap/spiders/craigspider.py

Answer (score 1):

I could't find any errors while giving request from your method1 (parse_item).

```
def parse_item(self, response):
    # from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    # inspect_response(response)
    item = Advertisement()
    location = response.url.split('/')[2].split('.')[0]
    detail_link_prefix = 'http://' + response.url.split('/')[2]
    selectors = response.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]')
    # pdb.set_trace()
    for sel in selectors:
        date_str = sel.xpath('//span[@class="pl"]/time/@datetime').extract()[0]
        item['post_datetime'] = to_datetime_object(date_str)
        item['post_title'] = sel.xpath('a/text()').extract()[0]
        extracted_link = sel.xpath('a/@href').extract()[0]

        # Check whether the url is absolute or relative as it varies
        # pdb.set_trace()
        if extracted_link.split('/')[0] == u'http:':
            detail_link = extracted_link
        else:
            detail_link = detail_link_prefix + extracted_link

        item['post_detail_link'] = detail_link
        price = sel.xpath('following-sibling::*/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract()
        if len(price) != 0:
            item['price'] = price[0]
        else:
            item['price'] = 'Not Mentioned'
        item['location'] = location
        # yield item
        yield scrapy.Request(detail_link, self.parse_item_details, meta={'item': item})

def parse_item_details(self, response):
    # from scrapy.shell import inspect_response
    # inspect_response(response)
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['model_year'] = response.xpath('//p[@class="attrgroup"]/span')[0].xpath('b/text()').extract()[0]
    return item
```

**model_year** field was missing in your items.py
so the items.py will looks like

```
class Advertisement(scrapy.Item):
    post_datetime = scrapy.Field()
    post_title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
    post_detail_link = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    model_year = scrapy.Field()
```

appending the sample output here

```
{"model_year": "2009 Ford Ranger", "post_title": "2009 Ford Ranger     pickup w/shell", "price": "$8495", "post_detail_link": "http://redding.craigslist.org/cto/4856643697.html", "location": "siskiyou", "post_datetime": "2015-03-23 17:41:00"}, 
{"model_year": "2011 ford ranger", "post_title": "[UPDATE]2006 ford ranger", "price": "$5500", "post_detail_link": "http://yubasutter.craigslist.org/cto/4883561404.html", "location": "sacramento", "post_datetime": "2015-03-24 21:43:00"},
```